# Is the term "morbid curiosity" generally negative or positive?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, phrase-meaning

In my experience, someone who asks things out of "**morbid curiosity**" generally seems to do so for the "sake of fulfilling their curiosity" with no other motivation beyond boredom, a random thought (lol ADHD), and so on.

However looking it up, the term seems to refer with an obsession with morbid topics, or anything generally negative, about death and disease, etc.

That said, if I say that I ask a question on here or Quora "out of morbid curiosity", is that an incorrect usage of the terminology?

Comment: How literal do you want to be?  This could be a matter of opinion.

Comment: I think it's kind of like "guilty pleasure". It sounds negative, but not extremely so.

Comment: I think it’s highly negative. From wikipedia, quoted in another answer:

A morbid curiosity exemplifies addictive curiosity. It has as its object death, violence, or any other event that may cause harm physically or emotionally, the addictive emotion being explainable by meta-emotions exercising pressure on the spontaneous curiosity itself.

Comment: Can you provide examples of "morbid curiosity" being used in the sense of "for the sake of fulfilling curiosity?" In what way would that be different from saying "out of curiosity?"

Comment: It is a phrase perhaps often used without strict accuracy, or with tongue in cheek, as a hyperbolic replacement for "idle curiosity." I will refrain from making any jokes about the morbidity of participation in either Stack Exchange or Quora.

Comment: @GArthurBrown so friends and family have used the term when implying a strong personal desire to want to know or understand something.  So for instance... I was recently doing some woodworking, fixing some benches, and a family member saw what I was doing and asked "Out of morbid curiosity, why did you set the bench upside down?"

I had done it as I needed to re-sand and scrape stuff off, and she didn't know what I was doing at the time.

Comment: I’d call that an incorrect usage.  But it’s likely idiosyncratic for the speaker. I wouldn’t overtly correct them, but I might be tempted to ask in a jocular manner, “What so morbid about it?”

Comment: In the 2017 NCBI paper [Choosing the negative: A behavioral demonstration of morbid curiosity, by
Suzanne Oosterwijk](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5500011/) the author sees fit (and correctly so) to provide a stipulative definition: 'In this paper, the term **morbid curiosity** is used to specify curiosity for information involving death, violence or harm, but not an “unhealthy” or “abnormal” form of curiosity.' But this is at odds with the everyday usage: ...

Comment: 'If you describe a person or their interest in something as morbid, you mean that they are very interested in unpleasant things, especially death, and you think this is strange. [disapproval]'. [[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/morbid-curiosity)] So the default usage, according to the Collins research team, includes the 'unhealthy' and 'abnormal' qualifiers.

Answer (score 3):

> mor·bid  (môr′bĭd)   adj.
>
> 1. Given to or characterized by unwholesome thoughts or feelings, especially of death or disease: read the account of the murder with a
>    morbid interest.
> 2. a. Of, relating to, or caused by disease; pathological or diseased: morbid changes in tissues.
>    b. Psychologically unhealthy or
>    unwholesome: a morbid fear of heights. [Latin morbidus, diseased, from
>    morbus, disease; see mer- in the Appendix of Indo-European roots.]

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=morbid

Why assume, as suggested in comments, that *morbid* means something less than its usual meaning in the phrase *morbid curiosity*?

Try reading some of the snippets https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=morbid+curiosity&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmorbid%20curiosity%3B%2Cc0 here to get a better idea of how the phrase is used.

Comment: This was used (of many places) in a movie of W.C. Fields where he cheated a man by betting on who could cut the highest card. When he cut he did not show the man the card (a five) but called it an ace. The man said he did not quite see the card. Fields angrily goes though the deck to find an ace telling the man, "This will satisfy your morbid curiosity. There it is, an ace." Here it is used to embarrass the other man into accepting the abuse he had been given. A loquacious dodge if ever there was one.

Comment: @Elliot That’s a humorous use, which only works if you first attribute the correct meaning.

Answer (score -1):

### Words can change meaning over long term usage

The term "morbid" in "morbid curiosity" originally meant "to an unhealthy degree". However, words sometimes change meaning entirely. "Terrific" used to mean something negative (evoking terror), but today its meaning is commonly understood to be positive.

I suspect the same may have happened with the "morbid" in "morbid curiosity", where it is not longer an expression of negativity, but rather one of intensity, i.e. meaning *very* curious, as opposed to *detrimentally* curious.

If the inherently negative connotation is lost, which I suspect it is, then the only way we can interpret positivity or negativity is through context.

### Context is key

> He killed a lot of bugs.

Is this phrase negative or positive?

Well, if this is in the context of an exterminator's yearly review (or a Starship Trooper), it'd be positive; but when spoken by an animal conservationalist it'd be negative.

The same is true of your question. Context is key, and the context is missing.

It could be negative, e.g. when the morbid curiosity caused something negative in the person's life (he lost his job). Or it could be positive, e.g. if the morbid curiosity caused something positive (he found the cure to cancer).

Comment: I was wondering if this is the case.  I also find it sad that you were downvoted.  TECHNICALLY, by definition, it's absolutely a negative thing, as evidenced by what I've found and the other answers/comments here.  But I'm suspecting that the common meaning has shifted a bit.  Just like how a certain four letter word that starts with F has shifted from working the land to... something far more vulgar and inappropriate.